# Url Generation error on redirects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a basic rails 4 scaffolded application and my routes.rb looks like this:

```
scope ':username' do
   resources :recipes
end
```

then I have the create and update actions in my controller looking like:

```
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @recipe.update(recipe_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @recipe, notice: 'Recipe was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'edit' }
      format.json { render json: @recipe.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

then the create:

```
def create
  @recipe = Recipe.new(recipe_params)
  @recipe.user = current_user.id
  respond_to do |format|
    if @recipe.save
      format.html { redirect_to @recipe, notice: 'Recipe was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @recipe }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @recipe.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

I'm getting this error:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Recipes#edit
```

Showing app/views/recipes/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"recipes", :username=>#<Recipe id: 9, name: "jdsafkd", yield: "", description: "", duration: "", author: "", url: "", user: 6, image: "", created_at: "2013-07-09 18:07:50", updated_at: "2013-07-09 18:07:50">, :id=>nil, :format=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

Here's the form partial:

```
<%= form_for(@recipe) do |f| %>
    <% if @recipe.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
           <h2><%= pluralize(@recipe.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this recipe from being saved:</h2>

        <ul>
         <% @recipe.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li><%= msg %></li>
         <% end %>
        </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>
    <div class="field">
       <%= f.label :image %><br>
       <%= f.text_field :image %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
       <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

So it looks like my redirect is creating a UrlGeneration error, but I don't know why.

Thanks for all help!

Comment: Can you provide form itself?

Comment: @JoeHalfFace, sure I posted with some of the fields removed (just to make it shorter, but they are all the same basically)

Comment: now I've noticed, that you are showing form with 'show' method, but usually it is 'new'. Why? Default route for show is /recipeis/:id, can you please provide link with wich you call show method? Something is for sure not right here.

Comment: May not be directly related to your problem, but I notice you have `@recipe.user = current_user.id` which is not going to work... should be `@recipe.user = current_user` or `@recipe.user_id = current_user.id`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this in your create & update methods:

```
redirect_to recipe_path(username: current_user.username, id: @recipe.id), notice: 'Recipe was successfully created.'
```